# Weka: Incompatible Training and Test Sets

Tags: classification, weka

I'm working on a **classificaton** problem on **Weka**. I'm taking am **arff** file as my training data and taking my test data from **database**. But they are incompatible. In Weka tool I can use the **InputMappedClassifier** and get over the problem. But I can't implement it in Java code. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to occur for me when the values are in a different order, e.g. one file says

```
@attribute class {Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}
```

and the other file says

```
@attribute class {Iris-virginica, Iris-versicolor}
```

so you might be able to fix this by converting the header information in the test set to match the training set.

Of course, if there are values in the test set that aren't in the training set, this won't work, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Another version of the same problem  if you read your data in from csv files, WEKA will order the class values in the order that they appear in the data, creating a problem like that described in the answer.